# Existe uma forma de fazer "migration" no RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

Olá!

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma alternativa para criar/alterar/remover exchanges, filas e bindings sem depender do framework (no meu caso, Spring) para isto.

Muitas vezes precisamos alterar o nome de uma Routing Key, Fila ou Exchange, e estes frameworks não permitem este tipo de alteração mais refinada. Como consequência, a tendência é que os nomes originais permaneçam. No futuro, isto acaba deixando confusa a organização das filas, pois você não consegue facilmente dar uma manutenção adequada no nome delas e eventualmente reorganizá-las.

O ideal para mim seria uma ferramenta que controle isto, como ocorre com as ferramentas de migração (*migration*), como o Liquibase, Flyway, etc.

Fazendo um paralelo com o banco de dados, atualmente deixar o Spring criar tudo no RabbitMQ me parece análogo a deixar ligado o *hbm2ddl* na opção "update" no Hibernate.

Sei que perguntas sobre ferramentas não é adequado no SO, mas como não encontrei nenhuma alternativa para este problema então achei que a pergunta era válida.

Comment: Recebi um voto negativo. Seria possível compartilhar o motivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de [pesquisar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50392969/2387977) sobre o assunto, creio que não posso aplicar uma estratégia de *migration* para as filas do RabbitMQ tal como faço para um banco de dados.

A possibilidade de alterar elas existe, mas não de uma forma declarativa. Precisa ser feito programando a alteração.

Com Spring, eu posso usar o `RabbitAdmin.declareBinding()` para fazer o *bind* com uma chave de rota (e/ou *exchange*) diferente. Posso usar o `RabbitAdmin.removeBinding()` para remover a antiga.

Não é possível alterar os argumentos de uma fila criada, como suas variáveis relacionadas a DLQ (*Dead Letter Queue*) ou durabilidade.

Para mover mensagens de uma fila antiga para uma fila nova, posso programar para fazer isto ou usar o plugin *shovel*, instalado no próprio RabbitMQ.